# Tomcat Thread Dump - Possible Stuck Thread

Tags: java, tomcat

I ran three thread dumps, 10 seconds apart, on a production server running Tomcat. I found that the same thread (same thread id) appears in all three thread dumps and is doing exactly the same thing - processing a JSP page. Does this mean it is stuck? Or could it be that the same thread from the Tomcat thread pool keeps getting assigned the same task over and over again.

This is a moderately big application and has a lot of servlets/JSP pages, business logic and a database. Also, it is fairly busy (around 20 requests per second). Tomcat is running standalone (not behind Apache).

Edit 1 (additional info): The home page normally takes significantly less than 10 seconds to render, so this can't be a typical single request to the home page.

**Edit 2: I took another thread dump hours later (but without restarting Tomcat) and this specific thread was doing something else. Does this CONCLUSIVELY mean that the thread was not stuck?**

Here is the the section of the thread dump for that specific thread (only one is listed as the other two are exactly the same):

```
"http-bio-8080-exec-220" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f5c801de800 nid=0x3151 runnable [0x00007f5c74d28000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:240)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:408)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteChars(OutputBuffer.java:487)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.append(CharChunk.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:152)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:336)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.print(JspWriterImpl.java:473)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.UrlSupport.doEndTag(UrlSupport.java:127)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.site.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005furl_005f22(home_jsp.java:1172)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.site.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f2(home_jsp.java:1141)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.site.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(home_jsp.java:1102)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.site.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at inspirasites.servlets.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:102)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at inspirasites.filters.CharEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharEncodingFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at inspirasites.filters.SiteFilter.doFilter(SiteFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    - locked <0x00000000e12fb330> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Yes, it could be stuck or the same thread performing the same task (Tomcat re-uses threads as much as possible). HTTP BIO is a blocking kind of connector, so most time would be spend reading from or (in this case) writing to a socket. There is no time-out on writing to a socket and if the receiver is really slow in processing the received bytes (e.g. swapping), the thread might be stuck (until the connection is closed or lost). But with a sample of three and 20 request per second, a re-used thread performing the same task is not unlikely.

Comment: @vanOekel First of all, you should make this an answer because it is extremely useful. Also, I have a follow-up question: Assuming the thread is stuck, then ALL thread dumps prior to restarting Tomcat would still show it doing the same task, right? In other words, Tomcat never kills a stuck thread. If that's the case, I can take another thread dump now and see if it is still there :)

Comment: I hesitate to make it an answer: somebody might have seen this behavior before and know what is going on ("unlikely" is not really an answer). Tomcat would not kill such a thread, but I would expect a warning/error log at some time ("connection reset" or something like that). Instead of thread dumps, you can also look at open connections ("netstat") - you should see the same "remote IP:port" come up (allthough this is not conclusive either - socket connections are usually re-used between requests ("HTTP keep-alive")).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently seen the exact same behaviour in our application and was able to reproduce it. It can be caused by a mis-behaving client that sends a request but does not consume the response data. In this case the socket will block, see the answers for this question: [Is an OutputStream in Java blocking? (Sockets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574596/is-an-outputstream-in-java-blocking-sockets)